# Bookmarklet title

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, titlebar

I want to write a bookmarklet that will have a title when it's dragged to the bookmarks bar. I have the bookmarklet that I want working, but it doesn't have a title by default.

I feel like there's probably a way to add a title property. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean

`<a href="javascript:alert('bla')">Alert Bla</a>`

which should create the title "Alert Bla" when dragged onto the bar

However please note the [chrome bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91624)

Alternatively  change the name of the bookmark in the book mark properties

Comment: That doesn't work. It shows me a title in the browser, but nothing in the bookmark bar. I want to prevent people from having to change the name of the bookmark manually.

Comment: What browser? Works for me in most browsers I know of

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: At least in safari you should get `Alert Bla` as default bookmark name